# groovy.lang.MissingMethodException With PowerMock and Jenkins getItemByFullName

Tags: mockito, jenkins-pipeline, powermockito, jenkins-shared-libraries

How can I use PowerMockito to ensure Jenkins static method returns my mocked object?

I see that if I have a test, that Jenkins is the mock.  However, if I add what looks like a valid PowerMockito.when for an additional static method, I get the error below.  I'm stumped.

**error**

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: 
 static jenkins.model.Jenkins.getItemByFullName() is applicable for argument types: 
 (java.lang.String) values: [job]

Possible solutions: 
  getItemByFullName(java.lang.String), 
  getItemByFullName(java.lang.String, java.lang.Class)
```

**code**

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest([Jenkins.class, Job.class])
class MyTest {
    def thisScript

    @Mock
    private Jenkins jenkins

    @Mock Job job

    MyClass myClass

    @Before
    void setUp() {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Jenkins.class)
        PowerMockito.when(Jenkins.getInstance()).thenReturn(jenkins)
        PowerMockito.when(Jenkins.getItemByFullName("job".toString())).thenReturn(job)

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A major oops on my part.  The getInstance method is static, getItemByFullName is not static.  So, here's the fix

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest([Jenkins.class, Job.class])
class MyTest {
    def thisScript

    @Mock
    private Jenkins jenkinsInstance

    @Mock Job job

    MyClass myClass

    @Before
    void setUp() {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Jenkins.class)
        PowerMockito.when(Jenkins.getInstance()).thenReturn(jenkins)
        PowerMockito.when(jenkinsInstance.getItemByFullName("job".toString())).thenReturn(job)

    }
```

I must mock the instance's method `jenkinsInstance.getItemByFullName` and not the `Jenkins.class` class's static method.

Comment: This code is identical to what is in your question.

Comment: @MattSchuchard it was J vs j but that's pretty hard to see so I modified the instance name